# Compiling error with omnet++5.1.1 and veins4.6

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have an error with omnet++5.1.1 and veins4.6. While build the project, I received error message as below:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -g -Wall -MMD -MP -MF out/gcc-debug//Attacker.d    -isystem /usr/include -isystem /mingw64/include -fno-stack-protector  -DXMLPARSER=libxml -DPREFER_QTENV -DWITH_QTENV -DWITH_TKENV -DWITH_PARSIM -DWITH_NETBUILDER -DWITH_OSG -DWITH_OSGEARTH  -DINET_IMPORT  -I/c/Users/xiruoliu/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/include -o out/gcc-debug//Attacker.o Attacker.cc
In file included from Attacker.cc:21:0:
Attacker.h:26:68: fatal error: 
veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h: No such file or directory
#include "veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h"
                                                                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:105: out/gcc-debug//Attacker.o] Error 1
```

I also tried to add the veins directory in makefile or change the directory in include statement to the complete path as #include "/c/Users/xiruoliu/src/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h". But it still failed.
The code used to work with oment++5.0 and veins4.5. Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: A verbose make run (append V=1 to the make command line) might shed some light on this. You can see which directories are used as base directories for searching include files.

Comment: I tried make V=1 and the directories shown are:
 -DINET_IMPORT C:/Users/xiruoliu/src/veins-4.6 -I/c/Users/xiruoliu/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/include

Comment: The command you mentioned only has one -I option and this is for OMNeT++ modules, not for Veins modules. Something must be wrong with your installation. You might want to try building from the command line. Alternatively, a fresh install might help.

Comment: I re-make veins and my own project in the directory of omnetpp-5.1.1/samples, but it still does not work. Then I tried to modify the makefile of my proejct (replace INCLUDE_PATH = -I. with INCLUDE_PATH = -I/c/Users/xiruoliu/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/samples/veins-4.6). From the compilation output, I have " -I/c/Users/xiruoliu/src/omnetpp-5.1.1/samples/veins-4.6" included, but still I have the same error message. What is the correct path I should include?

Comment: You could try opening an OMNeT++ command line, change to the Veins directory (cd .., cd veins-4.6), then run ./configure followed by make V=1

Comment: It is very weird that the makefile is overwritten when I compile it. In the make file, I tried to include veins directory by changing "INCLUDE_PATH = -I. -I$(INET_PROJ)/src"  to  "INCLUDE_PATH = -I. -I$(INET_PROJ)/src -I../veins/src". However, after I compile it, the include path changed to "INCLUDE_PATH = -I. -I$(INET_PROJ)/src -Isrc" automatically. Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you checked the makemake configuration of your project after upgrading OMNeT++? Right click on your project, open its preferences and check that makemake is configured to automatically add include paths exported from referenced projects. Also check that your project references the Veins project. If you need guidance with this step, I will be happy to provide a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for your instructions, Christoph! I finally resolved this issue by manually adding the veins directory into Makemake options -> compile -> included path. And now it compiles, but when I run it, I receives error "Cannot load library '../inet/src//libINET.dll'". libINET.dll is in inet/src directory. I tried re-build inet, veins and my own project, but it does not work.

Comment: `../inet` sounds like the OMNeT++ IDE expects the INET Framework to be installed exactly one folder up from your simulation, in a subdirectory called `inet`. Can you confirm this to be true? Otherwise, you will likely need to supply custom command line options to `opp_run` or launch your simulation from the command line altogether

Comment: My simulation is in the same folder as inet. They are at same directory level. I configured link option in Makemake to INET and added inet path to paths and symbols to solve this issue.